# How to draw single point efficiently

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I have a water surface I want to simulate. In order to add a rain drop to the surface I need to draw just a single point.

I have a code (in OpenGL 2.0):

```
float rainDrop[3] = { pos }; 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, rainDrop);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

**How to port this code to OpenGL 3.* ?** efficiently of course.

My idea is to just use simple buffer (with one element) and map it and draw this single point:

```
float rainDrop[3] = { pos }; 
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3*sizeof(float), rainDrop);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

But maybe another option would be to have one static buffer and change uniform values for the vertex shader?

I do not want to change my 'algorithm' so let just focus on drawing this one point.

Comment: You seriously want to simulate a _single_ rain drop on your entire water surface? I have done something similar to this in the past, using a simulation that ran in fragment shaders and wrote to a texture; I created cluster groups for the particles and periodically drew into a low-resolution depth / normal G-Buffer to detect and respond to particle collisions. In any event, sampling vertex positions from textures is actually a pretty practical approach to particles on modern hardware (sans compute shaders, which are of course the latest and greatest way to do this completely on the GPU).

Comment: I would like to actually update one or two pixels in the texture containing height data. So maybe simple glTexSubImage would be enough?

Comment: Are you using this height-map texture to compute the vertex positions in a vertex shader every frame? This sounds like a relatively static operation (e.g. you're really only dynamically changing the vertices once in a while), transform feedback _might_ be a better approach in OpenGL 3.*. You do have the benefit when using a texture-based height-map of using texture filtering to handle LOD, but you wind up doing a lot more computation/memory fetching on every frame than you probably need to.

Comment: I actually compute normal map out of the height map data and then apply height map on a simple quad. No need for transform feedback I think.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you specify vertex coordinates in a VBO. When drawing a small number of primitives, it really shouldn't make much of a difference which option you choose. The performance difference should trivial compared to other rendering operations...